# Can't remove cookies, which are generated by PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, firefox, cookies

Here is how I create cookie in PHP and Javascript

PHP, before loading a page, I first create cookie via PHP .

`setcookie('my_key', $value, 0,ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH);`

Javascript. I'm actually using jquery with this [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

When dropdown changed, I change the cookie value.

`jQuery.cookie("my_key", selected);`

In Google Chrome, everything works as what I expected.

The value of `my_key` cookie will be altered when dropdown changed.

In firefox, it generates another identical cookie.

yes, it is identical to the `my_key` cookie generated by PHP:

*same name, same expire(browser session), same domain, same path, same httponly(blank), same security(blank)*

The only difference is the new cookie is set to new value.

I try `jQuery.removeCookie('my_key')` but it can only delete the new cookie.

I'm not sure if it is a bug of firefox, or I did something wrong. But, truly, it is an annoying issue.

---

**Update 1:** it's true that I didn't specific path in javascript and right now I can change the cookie which is generated by PHP when I set the path.  But still not able to delete the cookie via JS.

FYI, I'm able to delete cookies in PHP but just can't delete them in JS.

Comment: Are you using the default path?

Comment: Have you checked what cookie gets delivered back to the PHP?

Comment: @Spokey  yep, thanks for reminder. I set path `jQuery.cookie("my_key", selected,{'path':'/admin'});` and I can change the cookie rather than creating a new one. but still not able to remove the cookie.

Comment: tried to set that cookie to ""?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum okay. I posted and will accept it as answer 2 days later (it's rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer inspired by Spokey and MightyPork:

- 1, set path to `jQuery.cookie`
- 2, use `jQuery.cookie("my_key", '',{expires: -1,path:'/admin'});` instead of `jQuery.removeCookie`

**Update:**

I did use jQuery.removeCookie('my_key',{path:'/admin'}) last night but not working. And I just now try again this morning, it's working. Maybe I was too tired last night.

**Conclusion**

The whole thing is about Path. I think, from my tests, perhaps, firefox has more strict standards than google chrome about cookie manipulation.

Comment: I had the same issue and I ended up using $.removeCookie(cookie_name,{path:'/'}); (specifying the path worked) and that worked.